Need help with a script to link files in a directory
I'm new to bash scripting and wanted to make a script that will get user input and hard link all the files of a directory to another one. So far I have this:

read -p "What directory do you want to link? " dir

items=$(ls -m $dir -Q | tr -d '\n'' ')

read -p "Where do you want to link the files? " outdir

echo "Linking files: $items to: $outdir"

read -p "Continue? (y/N) " confirmation

if [ $confirmation == "y" ] || [ $confirmation == "Y" ]; then
    ln $dir/{$items} $outdir
else
    kill -SIGTERM $$
fi

When I input /home/ethan/test and /home/ethan/test2 I get ln: failed to access '/home/ethan/test/{"test1","test2"}': No such file or directory
Also the contents of /home/ethan/test is two files, test1 and test2 and I'm on Arch.
Could anyone help me figure out what needs to change to get it working? Thanks.

A single call to ln is not going to link multiple items.   This is a job for rsync.

For a short utility script like this, I would suggest not making it interactive.  The user likely already knows exactly what directory they want to make a copy of in the manner that you describe, and allowing the user to make use of tab-completion and/or filename globbing on the command line makes it more likely that they get the arguments right compared to if having to type them in from memory.
Also, I would avoid using ls for anything other than looking at lists of files.  Don't use ls in a script for reading filenames.  It's better to just use a filename globbing pattern.  This is discussed in some detail in this other Q/A: Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?
To exit a script, either let the execution run to the end, or use exit.  Don't use kill.  Also, in general, double quote all variable expansions to avoid word-splitting and unwanted filename globbing (see When is double-quoting necessary?).
Your specific error is due to trying to use a shell variable in a brace expansion.  This is not possible in bash (see e.g. Combine brace and variable expansion in one line).
You would have further issues if the user wanted to work with directories with names starting with dashes.

Rather than using ls and combining its output into some sort of list that is used in a brace expansion (which would disqualify filenames that contain commas, newlines and probably a few other characters),
I would use rsync with its --link-dest option for this, wrapped into a shell function or shell script for convenience:
#!/bin/sh -

# The two expected arguments are
#     1. an existing source directory, and
#     2. a possibly existing destination directory

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    printf 'Not a directory: %s\n' "$1" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ -e "$2" ] && [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
    printf 'Not a directory: %s\n' "$2" >&2
    exit 1
fi

rsync -a --link-dest="$(readlink -f -- "$1")" -- "$1/" "$2"

We start by ensuring that the user has given us valid arguments. For this script, that means that the first argument (the source) must be an existing directory and that the second argument (the destination) must either not exist or be a directory, too.
We use readlink -f to ensure that the absolute path to the source directory is used with the --link-dest option of rsync as it would otherwise interpret the path relative to the destination directory path.  The readlink utility is not standard, but is commonly available.
Using rsync in this way ensures that the source directory is recursively recreated at the destination directory path and that (if the source and destination are on the same filesystem) the non-directory files are hard-linked.  If the source and destination paths are on different filesystems, the source directory path is recursively copied instead, without creating any hard links.
Note that we add a slash to the end of the source argument in the call to rsync.  We do this to copy the source directory's content, not the directory itself.
I wrote the script as a /bin/sh script, not as a bash script, since it does not use any special bash features.
Testing:
$ tree src
src
|-- data.dat
|-- subdir1
|   `-- myfile.txt
`-- subdir2
    `-- myfile.txt

2 directories, 3 files

$ linkcp src dst1

Notice how the link count for each of the files is 2:
$ ls -l dst1
total 8
-rw-r--r--  2 myself  wheel    0 Apr  6 07:47 data.dat
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Apr  6 07:47 subdir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Apr  6 07:47 subdir2
$ ls -l dst1/subdir*
dst1/subdir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  2 myself  wheel  0 Apr  6 07:47 myfile.txt

dst1/subdir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  2 myself  wheel  0 Apr  6 07:47 myfile.txt

$ linkcp src dst2

The link count now goes up to 3 as we made another copy of the src structure:
$ ls -l dst2
total 8
-rw-r--r--  3 myself  wheel    0 Apr  6 07:47 data.dat
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Apr  6 07:47 subdir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Apr  6 07:47 subdir2
$ ls -l dst2/subdir*
dst2/subdir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  3 myself  wheel  0 Apr  6 07:47 myfile.txt

dst2/subdir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  3 myself  wheel  0 Apr  6 07:47 myfile.txt


Works like a charm! Thank you so much for your time putting all of this together.
